# MYSQL Query for combobox

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two  tables in my database.namely books and bookidofid. where bookidofid from books table is referenced to bookidofid from bookidofid table

Table books

```
bookid bookname bookidofid                     
0         A       0                            
1         B       0                            
2         C       1                            
3         D       2                            
4         E       3
```

Table bookidofid

```
bookidofid
0
1
2
3
```

but in UI, I have made bookidofid as combobox . In that combobox, I have added all booknames. I have got it .

but When I edit E, I want A,B,C,D in the combobox. 
I will explain this with example

```
        _ _ North America __USA___Washington_ XX
        |
        |
America_|
        |
        |__ _ South America_Brazil__Rio di Janerio _YY
```

When I edit XX in bookname text box, I need America,North America ,USA, Washington in bookidofid combobox.
 When I edit YY in bookname text box, I need America,South America,Brazil, Rio di Janerio in bookidofid combobox.

Based on this example, I need a mysql query. I have tried but I couldn't get the correct query for this problem. 
I am doing this one in JAVA.

EDIT: OP's Query

```
select bookname 
from books b,
bookidofid bo 
from bookidofid 
where b.bookidofid=bo.bookidofid;
```

(it will return all book names in the combobox)

FOR EDIT:

```
select bookname,bookid,bookidofid 
from books b 
where bookname NOT IN (select bookidofid from bookidofid bo)
```

Comment: can you post the sql query you have tried? it's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I got the result for this query  select bookname from books b,bookidofid bo from bookidofid where b.bookidofid=bo.bookidofid; (it will return all book names in the combobox)

FOR EDIT:  select bookname,bookid,bookidofid from books b where bookname NOT IN (select bookidofid from bookidofid bo );

Comment: please take a look on the example (America)

Comment: your first query is syntactically incorrect (unless you made a typo in the comment). your second query doesn't make sense either: bookname has not relation to bookidofid.

Comment: Can you tell me the second query ? Based on that example. I was struggling for 3 days